# Hidden Markov Model with response and independent variable

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I need to fit a HMM for a machine/process that links some input variable to an output variable. When plotting the values, it is clear that there is a time series pattern. This repeating pattern is driven by the inputs, but also the hidden process inside the machine linking Input and Output. This hidden process has states. So now I want to fit a HMM with Output as the response and Input as the independent variable.

I'm new to HMM and I did some reading. I understand that one can fit a HMM for a dataset with observations. But in my case, I don't only have observations (the outputs) but also inputs that drive the outputs. So I have an independent variable.

How can I fit this HMM in R?

Comment: You need to spell out much more clearly what kind of model you're dealing with, your description is extremely vague.

Comment: Well, it's actually all the information I have. I have an input -> process -> output. The process has states and I have to infer these states using HMM.

Comment: But you know the states?

Comment: @Forgottenscience No, I don't know them either, but I was planning to use different number of states and comparing the models using BIC. The problem is that I find all this information on HMM when there are only observations (outputs), but no information on HMM when there is also an independent variable.

Comment: I don't see a reason to talk about the BIC yet. I propose you write out in much more mathematical detail what your setup actually is.